# Angular Material Checkboxes and bulk selections with custom datasource

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi I'm trying to implement the code found [here, for handling checkboxes, that can be used for bulk actions in a datagrid](https://stackblitz.com/angular/nadagybyroq?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts)

The thing is that I'm using a custom datasource, which handles my paging and filtering

I understand that the data is pushed to an instance of a selectionModel class and an can retrieve info from that when ready??

These are the fuctions:

```
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
```

I'm having trouble with these lines:

```
const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;

this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
```

Basically, data does not exist on my data service

My service takes an object with filtering, sorting, returned number of items, page number

```
this.dataSource.loadUsers(this.obj);

this.obj =
      {
        Page: this.paginator.pageIndex,
        NumberOfItems: this.paginator.pageSize,
        Filters: [ {} ],
        Sorting: {
          Property: this.sort.active,
          Direction: sortDirection
        }
  }
```

As well what the code for the link does is select all items, I want some thing that will only select the items that can be seen, if you are paging you don't want to select items on next page

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone else comes across this, this is how I handled it:

I already had a public behaviour subject in my custom data service, every time data was requested from the api the subject emits, other info for my app, (paging info) I put another property in that subject to carry, the array of users

```
this.pagedInfoSubject.next({ pageNumber: pageNumber, totalItems: totalItems, users:users });
```

In my ts file where I subscribe to this observable:

```
let conn = this.dataSource.pagedInfoSubject
      .skip(1)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.selection.clear();
        this.totalItems = data.totalItems;
        this.usersData = data.users//array of users
        console.log(this.usersData)
      });
```

And updated the code for the checkboxes to:

```
isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.usersData.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
        this.selection.clear() :
        this.usersData.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
```

Basically using the array passed back for the loop

If anyone can see a better way, or needs me to elaborate, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

For an easier solution:

Just in case someone is still struggling with the above solution. the variable "data" is non existing in your customDataSource, but there should be a BehaviorSubject `public userSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User[]>([])` which holds the data for the dataTable (in my case a list of Users). You can access the data by just going `this.datasource.userSubject.getValue()`, and thus get the length of the actual data in the page using .length();

I changed the following lines:

```js
const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;

this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
```

to:

```js
const numRows = this.dataSource.userSubject.getValue().length;

this.dataSource.userSubject.getValue().forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
```